# Hexadecimal in String to Hexadecimal in Integer

Tags: c++, std

I want to know how to convert something like `string x = "1f"` to `int y = 0x1f`, every topic I found was solved by turning it to simply the integer value of it (31) or turning the string to a hexadecimal equivalent `"Hello" > 48656C6C6F`

```
std::stringstream Strm;
std::string Stng = "1f";
Strm << Stng;
int Hexa;
Strm >> std::hex >> Hexa;
cout << Hexa;
```

This closest I could get to it (but turned out it just converts it to integer)

EDIT: I guess my problem was I didn't know it must be stored as an integer and can be only shown as hexadecimal if i add std::hex after cout, that was stupid sorry

Comment: are you just looking to print the number in base 16? if so: cout << std::hex << Hexa.  Note: "int y = 0x1f" translates to 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011111 (assuming 32bit int) as far as the processor is concerned.

Comment: "it just converts it to integer" — this is to be expected. There are no such things as hexadecimal integers.

Comment: `int y = 0x1f` and `int y = 31` are identical.  `int` has no notion of the base you express it in.

Comment: 0x1F and 31 are both the same integer. Why do this cause so much confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers don't carry labels saying 'I'm a decimal integer' or 'I'm a hexadecimal integer'. All integers are the same. So if you have found some code that converts a hexadecimal string to an integer then that is the code you should use.

Once you have your integer you can then *choose* to print it out in hexadecimal if you want. You do that with `hex`

```
int hexa = ...;
cout << hex << hexa; // prints an int in hexadecimal form
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)
2. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

The last will throw an exception if the input string is not a proper hexadecimal number.

And remember, in the computer **all** integers are stored in binary, hexadecimal is just a presentation. For example, the ASCII character `'a'` is the same as decimal number `97` and the same as octal number `141` and the same as hexadecimal number `61` and the same as binary number (which it is ultimately is stored as in memory) `01100001`.

Answer (score 0):

One quite fast solutions is using boost::lexical cast. You can find everything here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html